# How to consume bokeh with mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, mypy

I am using bokeh library and it states that it uses mypy internally. Thus, I infer it has good typing information which I have confirmed looking the source code.

However, I notice that using mypy in my own project that imports bokeh still produces errors.
How I should configure mypy in my side to gracefully and correctly use the bokeh typing in when I consume the library in my project?

for example, I receive this kind of error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Override[str]")  [assignment]
```

Comment: Can you post the code that produces that error?

Comment: Bokeh's property system utilizes low-level and advanced descriptor protocol methods to streamline the Python<-->JS runtime coordination. It's foundational to everything in Bokeh and pre-dates wide usage of static typing in Python. Unfortunately, it's also not especially compatible with static typing, and it's unclear what, if anything, can be done about that. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13292